# awk: extract data from a column by name rather than position

Tags: awk

I have a text file that is comma delimited. The first line is a list of field names, and subsequent lines contain data. I'll get new versions of the file, and I want to extract all the values from a particular column by name rather than by column number.  (I.e. the column I want may be in different positions in different versions of the file.)

For example, here are two files:

```
foo,bar,interesting,junk
1,2,gold,ramjet
2,25,diamonds,superfluous
```

and

```
foo,bar,baz,interesting,junk,morejunk
5,3,smurf,platinum,garbage,scrap
6,2.5,mushroom,sodium,liverwurst,eew
```

I'd like a single script that will go through multiple files, extracting the minerals in the "interesting" column. :-)

What I've got so far is something that works on ONE file, but I know that awk is more elegant than this. How do I clean this up and make it work on multiple files at once?

```
BEGIN {
    FS=",";
}

NR == 1 {
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if($i=="interesting") {
            col=i;
        }
    }
}

NR > 1 {
  print $col;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this without a comment. Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty darn close already.  Just use FNR instead of NR, for "File NR".

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="," }

FNR==1 {
  for (col=1;col<=NF;col++)
    if ($col=="interesting")
      next
}

{ print $col }
```

Or if you like:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="," }

FNR==1 { for (col=1;$col!="interesting";col++); next }

{ print $col }
```

Or if you prefer one-liners:

```
$ awk -F, -v txt="interesting" 'FNR==1{for(c=1;$c!=txt;c++);next} {print $c}' file1 file2
```

Of course, be careful that you actually have the specified column, or you may find yourself in an endless loop. You can probably figure out the extra condition that saves you from that risk.

Note that in awk, you only need to terminate commands with semicolons if they are followed by another command.  Thus, you would do this:

```
command1; command2
```

But you can drop the semicolon if you separate commands with newlines:

```
command1
command2
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i; next }
{ print $(f["interesting"]) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
gold
diamonds
platinum
sodium
```

Creating a name->value array is always the best approach when it's applicable. It keeps every part of the code simple and decoupled from the rest of the code, and it sets you up for doing other things like changing the order of the fields when you output the results, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i; next }
{ print $(f["junk"]), $(f["interesting"]), $(f["bar"]) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
ramjet,gold,2
superfluous,diamonds,25
garbage,platinum,3
liverwurst,sodium,2.5
```

Comment: Ed, I'm giving ghoti the checkmark because he explained my mistake, improved on my code and was first, but I really like the approach you mention here, and I'll certainly use it in the future, assuming I can recognize where it's applicable. :-) Thank you very much for your answer.